# Is running Testing script using override Entrypoint an antipattern in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have a following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app
 
ADD main.py /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3",  "main.py" ]
```

I have a prerequisite test that runs before deployment that verifies connection, input files, etc

So I added testing script to Docker image like

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /app
 
ADD main.py /app
ADD test.py /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3",  "main.py" ]
```

For testing, I am running docker container like

```
docker run --entrypoint python3 myImage test.py
```

Is this an anti pattern in Docker? Would it be better practice to create separate Testing container image?

Answer (score 0):

I normally recommend using `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT`, for two reasons.

```sh
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]  # not ENTRYPOINT
```

Your invocation to run the test script illustrates one of them.  Overriding an `ENTRYPOINT` is a little awkward, but overriding the `CMD` is pretty straightforward; you can just run

```sh
docker run myImage \
  python3 test.py
```

with the command assembled more naturally.

A second reason to prefer `CMD` has to do with what exactly that test script does:  it "verifies connection, input files, etc".  It's very reasonable to want to run this script at container startup time, and if it succeeds, go on to run the main application.  You could write a wrapper script that took some command as arguments, ran the test script, and if it was successful, launched the command it was given:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Run the verification script
if ! python3 test.py ; then
  echo 'Pre-launch verification failed, exiting' >&2
  exit 1
fi

# If that succeeded, run the command passed to us as arguments
exec "$@"
```

Now you can use that script as the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.  When you [have both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) the `CMD` gets passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`, which is exactly what this script expects.

```sh
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app

# Prefer COPY to ADD, unless you specifically need URL fetching or
# archive unpacking.  Use a relative path for the COPY destination
# to avoid repeating the path name.
COPY main.py test.py entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"] # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]        # can be any valid CMD
```

With this setup, if you replace the `CMD` at the `docker run` command, the `ENTRYPOINT` is still in effect.

```sh
# Get an interactive debugging shell in this container, but only
# after the startup-time tests pass.
docker run --rm -it myImage /bin/sh

# I don't know why the startup-time tests aren't passing; skip even
# that.
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh myImage
```

(For a more general concept of testing, including your application's unit tests and integration tests, I'd generally launch these from outside Docker; I wouldn't build a special test-only container or include test code in my production image.  That's different from startup-time configuration checking, which is what you seem to be after.)